# Hibernate hbm2ddl validate - can't resolve all checks

Tags: hibernate, spring-roo, hbm2ddl

I got a big roo-script. Who generates Database in MySQL-5.6.10. I can successfully create the schema, I can add data to the database.

**but** If I switch from

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

There are many issues I can't resolve because of mysql convert from boolean to bit like:

```
Wrong column type in ... for column ... . Found bit, expected: boolean
```

Ok, now my Question:

**Is it necessary to Resolve all issues?**

**Should I forbid the usage with databases the *validate* create warnings?**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same problem by placing `none` in place of `create` or `validate`.

The one time that you create dbre.xml, it is not necessary to validate the model - only if you make a change in the structure of database. This may need a little more impact analysis, but this fix has worked for me before.

Comment: I like to use `validate` if it is necessary. Is it necessary?